# Hyperledger composer - Question about permissions ACL working, when different business network is invoked from one business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a question. 
- I have multiple Business networks, each having its own ACL (Say i have 3 such networks A, B & C).
- I also have a Top-level business network, which calls one of these networks A or B or C based on the needs.
- Now assume I call network A via the top-level network using the binded participant identity X. 
- If I use nativeAPI().invokechaincode() to call network A, will the permissions.ACL of network A be processed correctly for X?

Comment: No. You're calling it via Fabric shim API (Chaincodestub class).  Its documented in the docs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
As per the document, " getState, putState, deleteState, getStateByPartialCompositeKey, getQueryResult " are only mentioned. "Invokechaincode" is not mentioned. 
Also, I'm invoking another composer transaction function (exactly in the way how composer use to call the underlying fabric) and not a pure fabric application. 
In this case, when the identity of network A is bound with a participant of network B, ACL on network B for the respective participant is working for me.

Comment: right, sure - because he's bound to a participant of network B, where the authorization is taking place. You're simply binding the participant (in network B) to the real identity (irrespective of the business network).